# My simple introduction program to SDL does not build. Why am I getting these linker errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, sdl, linker-errors

So, I'm trying to use SDL for the first time and so far it has been a complete mess! I'm trying to get this to run, but everything that I have tried has failed. I have been following all the correct guides but it still will not run!

I am using `Visual Studio Ultimate 2010`.

This is all the code that I am trying to run:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    // Start SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    std::cout << "SDL has been initialized!\n";

    // Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    std::cout << "SDL has quit!" << std::endl;

    return 0x0;
}
```

The errors that the compiler yaks back are driving me nuts! Here they are:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SDL_TEST, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 7/6/2013 1:21:45 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\SDL_TEST.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit referenced in function _SDL_main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function _SDL_main
1>MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Tux\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SDL_TEST\Debug\SDL_TEST.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.59
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You need to link with the SDL library. Unfortunately, as it's about 3 years since I last had anything to do with SDL, I can't remember the details of how to set it.

Comment: @Mats Petersson Okay, I already linked to the x64 version the libraries and I would get the aforementioned linker errors, but when I changed to the x86 version, the build would succeed. Why is this?

Comment: if you are building a 64bit app you need to link with 64bit libs, and vice versa

Comment: Happens because you are building a Win32 binary as you can see in the header "Configuration: Debug Win32".

Comment: @RobertDinu I just now saw that. Well, that answers my question! Should I submit an answer?

Comment: @Tux: Courtesy says that the person who suggested the hint that gave you the right solution posts the answer (and gets the rep points)

Comment: @Tux post the answer if you have one.

Comment: Well, that would be you @MatsPetersson. If you want to.

Comment: @RobertDinu should post the answer, since he's the one that pointed out that you are compiling 32-bit and linking with 64-bit libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation fails because you are not linking with the correct libraries. You have linked with the 64bit libraries but you are trying to build a Win32 binary:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SDL_TEST, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
```

Linking with the 32bit libraries or switching to a Win64 binary should resolve your problem.